# How to create popover in button click in uitbaleview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Guys i am creating popover in uitableview cell button click in objective c.i need that type design.how to implement this one.i am using fbpopover and i already try custom but i am unable to find exact solution.

[image]

Comment: may be you can put one UIView over there and hide it, and on click of button show the UIView and Bring it to front. and for hide you can remove it from superview or just hide as u like..

Comment: ravi i have already try this one but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps,

1. In the `customtableviewCell` take one `UIButton` (says, `btnHidePost`) just below the setting button (says, `btnSetting`). Don't forget to give constraints.
2. create one mutable array which global in your class only. (says, `arrMutBtnSelected`)
3. Initially, in `viewDidLoad` do

`// array of bools, initially all false as not any button is selected
// arrPost is the array of your post, assumine here it is total count for your rows.
    for (int i=0; i < arrPost.count; i++) {
        [arrMutBtnSelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
    }`

4. In `cellForRow`

`if (arrMutBtnSelected[indexPath.row] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]) {
        fbCell.btnSetting.selected = true;
        fbCell.btHidePost.hidden = false;
    }
    else{
        fbCell.btnSetting.selected = false;
        fbCell.btHidePost.hidden = true;
    }
}`

5.On button action,

`[arrMutBtnSelected removeAllObjects];
         for (int i=0; i < arrPost.count; i++) {
         [arrMutBtnSelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
         }
         [arrMutBtnSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];`